# Windows encryption of users data

Tags: windows-10, encryption, privacy

I use a Windows 10 laptop that is also used by other people. All users have the administrator rights. I want to protect my profile folder C:\Users\myaccount from access by the other users, especially my .ost (Outlook) file, my private keys, stored passwords, browsers history, etc.

Is there a tool like ecryptfs for Windows? It seems the EFS is not complete solution and doesn't encrypt filenames and folders tree content.

Comment: EFS is indeed the solution.  Anyone without the certificate would be unable to access any of your files  They have the ability to see filenames but that is all they would see.  There is NO solution within Windows natively that would hide files from an Administrator.  Any third-party solution is easily defeated.  EFS certiccate can only be exported by the certificate owner and requires the user's pasword.

Comment: That is incorrect. Any third party solution with a reasonably strong encryption couldn't be defeated "easily"

Comment: Why is every user on this computer an admin? Is it a business/work computer you share or a personal device shared by several family members?

Comment: @mashuptwice - I am obviously talking about programs that "hide" files from another user.  The only solution the author could use is a VeraCrypt contain or a BitLocker encrypted VHDX mounted volume.

Comment: @Ramhound : I can't relocate my profile folder C:\Users\myaccount into VeraCrypt container. This latter must be unlocked before the user logon.

Comment: @user - You can put a container within your profile, then put your files, in that container.  You have chosen to make every user an Administrator, that means that by design, they can access every non-encrypted file on the system.

Comment: @Rambound : "_You can put a container within your profile..._". But the goal is to do the opposite, put the profile folder within the container. I also realized the C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming is not encrypted at all, even with a full EFS encryption of the profile folder.

Answer (score 1):

Any admin on this computer will have access to all the files on the computer. If they don't have permissions now they can just grant themselves permission.

So your only option for data privacy is to lock it with encryption, or store it off-computer on a removable storage device.